# Setting Correct PATH for Homebrew PHP

Tags: php, bash, homebrew

I used Homebrew to install PHP versions 5.4 and 5.5 on my system. However, it seems that even after installing and linking to php55 my computer is still trying to run the version initially used by the system.

```
php --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 19:05:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I believe Homebrew sets up PHP under '/usr/local/lib' and not '/usr/lib/'.

What do I need to do to correctly have my system use the Homebrew version of PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `/usr/local/bin` at the front of your `$PATH`. In your `~/.bashrc` file, add something like

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: This was it. I was incorrectly referencing the /lib folder in PATH instead of /bin. Surprised I didn't notice this earlier.